# How to log to multiple file using tracerx

Tags: c#-4.0, logging

I  am using Tracerx for logging . Currently all the logs are saved in a single file

```
Logger.GetLogger("name");
```

does not create a new file .I want every log to be in a separate file how do i implement it..?

Answer (score 0):

The log file name is not controlled by the string that you pass into `Logger.GetLogger(..)`. It is controlled by the name that you set when you initialize your log file. Here is a sample class that you can use as a template. In the `InitLogging` function, you'll want to change the properties `Logging.TextFileLogging.Name` and `Logging.BinaryFileLogging.Name` according to what you want the log named for that class.

```
 public class MyClass
 {
    // Declare a Logger instance for use by this class.
    private static readonly Logger _log = Logger.GetLogger("MyClass");

    // Initialize TracerX
    private static bool LogFileOpened = InitLogging();

    public void MyFunction()
    {
        using(_log.DebugCall())
        {
            //Do some stuff
            _log.Info("Doing some stuff in MyFunction");
        }
    }

    private static bool InitLogging()
    {
        // Load TracerX configuration from an XML file.
        Logger.Xml.Configure("TracerX.xml");;

        //Setup the name of the binary file
        Logger.BinaryFileLogging.CircularStartSizeKb = 0;
        Logger.BinaryFileLogging.Directory = "[path to my logs directory]";
        Logger.BinaryFileLogging.Name = "MyClassLog";

        //Setup the name of the text file
        Logger.TextFileLogging.CircularStartSizeKb = 0;
        Logger.TextFileLogging.Directory = "[path to my logs directory]";
        Logger.TextFileLogging.Name = "MyClassLog";

        if (Logger.TextFileLogging.IsOpen == false)
            Logger.TextFileLogging.Open();

        if (Logger.BinaryFileLogging.IsOpen == false)
            Logger.BinaryFileLogging.Open();

        return true;
    }

}
```

This should get you started. If you need further help, [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23424/TracerX-Logger-and-Viewer-for-NET) has pretty good examples.

Answer (score 0):

After two years this probably won't help you but...

Each Logger object has a property called BinaryFile that specifies the file used by that Logger.  The initial/default value of the BinaryFile property is the same for all Loggers which is why they all write to the same file.  If you want a given Logger to write to a different file you need to create a new BinaryFile for it.

The sample code below creates two Loggers (Log1 and Log2) and assigns a different BinaryFile (with a different file Name) to each.  BinaryFile has several other properties you could set, such as Directory, MaxSizeMb, FullFilePolicy, etc.  Note that you would also need to call the Open() method to actually open/create the file.

```
        Logger Log1 = Logger.GetLogger("name1");
        Log1.BinaryFile = new BinaryFile()
        {
            Name = "FileName_1"
        };


        Logger Log2 = Logger.GetLogger("name2");
        Log2.BinaryFile = new BinaryFile()
        {
            Name = "FileName_2"
        };
```